# Is Brownian motion on $[0,b]$ bounded?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Is Brownian motion on $[0,b]$ bounded? Or at least bounded with probability one. Since Brownian motion is continuous with probability $1$, I guess the answer is YES.

Comment: Each path is bounded (not just with prob. 1 - there are no exceptions), but the set of all paths is not bounded. That's because normal distributions have unbounded support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space, so that for each $\omega \in \Omega$ we have a function $t \mapsto B(\omega,t), t \in [0,\infty)$.  Almost all sample paths $B(\omega,\cdot)$ are continuous, hence bounded on any set $[0,b]$.  (Hans says "all" sample paths, but that will depend on how you define Brownian motion.)  On the other hand, for fixed $b$, the one random variable $B(\omega,b)$ has normal distribution with nonzero variance, so even that random variable is not a.s. bounded.  So, what do you mean by *bounded*?

Comment: So am I correct in saying that it is not uniformly bounded in the sense that there is no constant $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that a.s. $|B(t)| \leq M, \forall t \in [0,b]$? But just that, for every $\omega$, there is a.s. a $M_{\omega}$ such that $|B(t)| \leq M_{\omega}, \forall t \in [0,b]$?